# Stm32f407 Uart Dma Multiple Array Tx

Tags: stm32, uart, dma, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I tried  to send Buffer from stm32f407 to terminal.Type is uint8_t and array is 15000. My code is works. but when i try to send 2 buffer like 5000 array, there is problem for second buffer. I use normal mode.What i should do to sending succesfully?

```
 /* USART3 DMA Init */
/* USART3_TX Init */
hdma_usart3_tx.Instance = DMA1_Stream3;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.Channel = DMA_CHANNEL_4;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
hdma_usart3_tx.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_usart3_tx) != HAL_OK)
{
  Error_Handler();
}

__HAL_LINKDMA(huart,hdmatx,hdma_usart3_tx);

/* USART3 interrupt Init */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART3_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
```

/* USER CODE BEGIN USART3_MspInit 1 */

/* USER CODE END USART3_MspInit 1 */

```
void Send_Dataa(void)
```

{

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(wifi_uart, buf1, 5000);
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(wifi_uart, buf2, 5000);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you check the return code from HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(), you'll probably see it is returning HAL_BUSY. (Note you should always be checking the return codes from HAL functions.)

You'll need to wait until the first transmit is complete before starting the second transmit. You can use HAL_UART_GetState() to monitor the state of the UART.

The HAL does not chain together multiple DMA requests.

Comment: Thanks for give me information. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I used HAL_DMA_GetState and Dma is in busy state. How i can make it Ready state?

Comment: You can't make in 'Ready', you should wait until states changes. Keep polling `HAL_UART_GetState`

Comment: @emiter_v Just to be clear, HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA() configures a DMA transfer, then returns. The DMA transfer happens "in the background" while your code can continue to do other things. This is the main benefit of DMA. In your case, you don't have other things to do, so you'll need to wait until the first transfer completes before starting the new one. Hope that makes sense.